# Additional queries being performed from model connecting to a remote mysql database

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Everytime i call any method in my model i see the following four additional queries being performed. The model name is City. And im connecting to a remote mysql legacy database using connection_ninja(https://github.com/cherring/connection_ninja)

```
SET SQL_AUTO_IS_NULL=0, NAMES 'utf8', @@wait_timeout = 2147483   
SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM `City` 
SHOW TABLES LIKE 'City'  
SHOW CREATE TABLE `City`
```

The code for my model is as follows:

```
class CityRlOp < ActiveRecord::Base
  @conn = use_connection_ninja(:rl_op)
  self.table_name = 'City'

  def self.get_all_city_names
    city_names = Rails.cache.read "geomapping_city_names"
    if city_names.nil?
      city_names = []
      select("distinct city_name").each do |name|
        city_names.push name
      end
      Rails.cache.write "geomapping_city_names", city_names
    end
    city_names
  end

  def self.city_name_exists?(name)
    records = where(city_name: name)
    if records.count > 0
      city_names = Rails.cache.read "geomapping_city_names"
      city_names.push name
      Rails.cache.write "geomapping_city_names", city_names
      true
    else
      false
    end
  end
end
```

Are those queries needed everytime i hit the model ?

Please Help
Thank You

Comment: I think it depends on the fact you are using a custom model/table name. Since you have this `self.table_name = 'City'` I suppose it will look for that table every time you query the model/